# Hyperlink on console qpython for Android

Tags: android, python, console, kivy, qpython

I'm using `QPython` for android and want to print a clickable hyperlink on the console. Is there a built-in function I can do this? Or maybe `Kivy`?

Comment: console is not web browser - it can't display clickable link.

Answer (score 0):

I fear you expect `Terminal` (e.g. on Ubuntu) behavior on `bash` emulator running on Android. That won't work.

`Terminal` is too just a gui "wrapper" around the classic `bash` console, which can't display such things either.

With Kivy however you can create your own "wrapper" too i.e. your own console, which would be able to display anything you make it display. One of core devs did something [similar](https://github.com/inclement/Pyonic-interpreter) for Python console.

Comment: I used pythonista for iOS and it already supported the hyperlink. I hoped qpython would have the same preinstalled. I guess pythonista has its own wrapper as you described.

Thanks